# Pentaho CE 6.1 to CE 8.1 upgrade - project fails

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am trying to run a transformation with one parent .ktr and a few sub transformations (child .ktr). All maps run successfully when running on on original PDI 6.1. When running on the upgraded version PDI 8.1, the last step/Global-BulkLoad.ktr fails.
The log specifies which step in the sub transformation: Global-BulkLoad.ktr fails:

```
    2023/04/23 15:46:24 - Global-BulkLoad - Dispatching started for transformation [Global-BulkLoad]
2023/04/23 15:46:24 - Write JSON.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Error initializing UserDefinedJavaClass:
2023/04/23 15:46:24 - Write JSON.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2023/04/23 15:46:24 - Write JSON.0 - null
2023/04/23 15:46:24 - Write JSON.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Write JSON]
```

This step: Write JSON is a User Defined Java Class. I spent so much time on it, but was not able resolve. Please help.

Updated missing jars in the data-integration/lib folder
jsoup-1.10.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
jackson-core-2.6.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar

Comment: Without sharing information about the specifics of the code in Write JSON step you won't be able to get help. In any case, you'll probably need to debug that step in the new version to make it work, you built it in the past, so you'll probably be more capable of fixing it, or at least get a more meaningful error about what isn't working in the new version.